# Using built-in type guards to refine `unknown`/`object` value to a specific object type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Here's a naive attempt:

```js
const x: unknown = {a: 1};

if (
    typeof x === 'object' && 
    x !== null && 
    'a' in x && 
    typeof x.a === 'number' // error: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'object'.
) {
    console.log("x's type is a subtype of {a: number}");
}
```

Is there any way to use built-in type guards to discriminate here?

Comment: No, not with built-in ones.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732 about the `in` operator's failing here.  You can use a custom type guard or a type assertion; do you want an answer which explains the situation and talks about these alternative approaches?  Or just an answer that says "no" with a link to the relevant GitHub issue?

Comment: @jcalz the ideal would be some kind of generic helper method to perform this kind of check, however I'll also accept just a link to the GitHub issue and a brief explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently [narrowing an object type via the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) like `k in o` only works when `o` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and the result is that the union type is narrowed to just those members with a known `k` key. This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256). But in your case, by the time you check `"a" in x`, the apparent type of `x` is just [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), which is not a union, and does not have a known `"a"` key.  So the `in` operator check does nothing useful for you.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) asking for `in` to narrow non-union inputs as well by asserting that the checked property exists.  So something like `"a" in x` should narrow `x` from `object` to `{a: unknown}`.  It's not clear when or if this will be implemented in TypeScript.  For now there are workarounds.

For example, you can create your own [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) function which behaves the way you wanted `in` to behave, and then call it instead of `in`.  One way to do this might be:

```
function inOperator<K extends string, T extends object>(
  k: K, o: T
): o is T & Record<K, unknown> {
  return k in o;
}
```

And observe that it satisfies your use case:

```
const x: unknown = { a: 1 };

if (
  typeof x === 'object' &&
  x !== null &&
  inOperator('a', x) &&
  typeof x.a === 'number' // okay
) {
  x.a.toFixed(); // okay
  console.log("x's type is a subtype of {a: number}");
}
```

By the time `x.a.toFixed()` is called, `x.a` has successfully been narrowed to `number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMB5ADgUwE4EMpzYA8A0opgB5SZgAmAzovVNigOYA0iAKuVTQ0RwARgCtM0AHwAKANYAuRCS5xF3AJSK4yRrwBkiAEoTCtUl3CywcAO5hJiAN4BYAFCJE2TFBDYks5CQ4AG43AF83NwgEZkQKRUtrO0QAXidEXEUARkQw0Nc3GGBEaTcPKABPLDhiilSUtIByEXFoRsQ9PTK4xABCBsQwEAAbYY6u90CMHHxCaUbcRq4KdXHuyuragDpceqahgFthHEa3VZdJih2tggAxGApMWml1YMQAenehWVwK7uiwPQ4MNMFthnA2NIAEQURqMDaYHQZJggYQIoTFRyZQYgI44MJQ17hIA)

Comment: Really cool, thank you so much!